# Code involving default copy constructor should segfault, but works just fine

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

I was running a little experiment to better understand when constructors/destructors are implicitly called, and I discovered something really strange.

The following code invokes the default copy constructor when `myFunction()` is called. Before exiting the scope of myFunction(), my user-defined `~myClass()` is invoked, which should be calling `free()` on `dangerData`. However, this doesn't seem to be freeing `dangerData`!

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

class myClass {
    static int nextid;
    int myID;
    char *dangerData;

    public:

    myClass() {
        myID = nextid++;
        printf("Constructing myClass number %d\n", myID);
        dangerData = (char *)malloc(1024);
        dangerData[12] = 0;
    }

    ~myClass() {
        printf("Destructing myClass number %d. dangerData = %p\n", myID, (void *) dangerData);
        dangerData[12] = 'a'; //Mark the array
        free(dangerData); //This call chould free the array... but it doesn't!
    }

    void msg() {
        printf("Message from myClass number %d. dangerData[12] = %d\n", myID, dangerData[12]);
    }
};

int myClass::nextid = 1;

void myFunction(myClass param) {
    param.msg();
}

int main() {
    myClass m;
    myFunction(m); //Calls default copy constructor
    m.msg();
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this code is:

```
Constructing myClass number 1
Message from myClass number 1. dangerData[12] = 0
Destructing myClass number 1. dangerData = 02f71458. dangerData[12] = 0
Message from myClass number 1. dangerData[12] = 97
Destructing myClass number 1. dangerData = 02f71458. dangerData[12] = 97
```

The first call to the desctructor is *definitely* calling `free()` on the malloc'd array, however the call to `m.msg()` in `main()` can still access it without segfaulting!

Is this supposed to be happening?

Comment: accessing freed memory is undefined behavior it can result in a segfault but it isn't always going to result in segfault

Comment: That's undefined behavior - there is no guarantee that you will actually segfault or crash!

Comment: once i hit my finger with a hammer and it did not hurt. What can I conclude from it? ...nothing. I will still not hit my finger with a hammer and expect it to be fine

Comment: as @Tyker said, this is undefined behaviour. That means *anything* can happen, but there is no guarantee that the *same* thing will happen every time. Could work fine today, segfault tomorrow, and make demons fly out of your nose on Sunday.

Comment: Aside:  Why are you using malloc in c++?

Comment: @UKMonkey Was just an experiment to see what would happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this supposed to be happening?

Nothing particular is "supposed" or rather "expected" to happen here - you are invoking undefined behavior, so anything *could* happen, including "nothing".

> the call to m.msg() in main() can still access it without segfaulting!

This is not terribly surprising (but again, nothing you should ever count on). Freeing the memory more or less tells the OS that that memory can be reused/overwritten freely. The more focus there is on speed over safety between your compiler, OS and their settings, the less work they will invest into marking this memory as inaccessible, and since you just used that exact memory location you would have to run under very stringent OS checks to even get a segfault there. It is also exceedingly unlikely for that 13th character to be overwritten in the time between the two `msg()` calls, so you are likely to read back the same thing again.

But all this just pertains to this small example and is, again, nothing to rely on. Undefined behavior (somewhat unfortunately) does not automatically mean "your program will segfault now". It may do, or it may segfault two minutes later in a completely different part, or silently output wrong results, or format your hard drive. Or it may run as you intended, this one time.